# What's the downside of disabling PAM in OpenSSH if only public-key login is allowed?

Tags: ssh, pam

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by default has the following line

```
UsePAM yes
```

I read through available documentation and came to the conclusion that PAM is not used if I only use public-key login. What possible negative consequences could there be if I disable PAM? e.g.

```
UsePAM no
```

Comment: As Matthew suggests, your conclusion is incorrect. Public key authentication only skips the `auth` entries of your PAM configuration. `account` and `session` [are still used by sshd](http://serverfault.com/a/667338/152073) in this case. Turning this off would cause [inconsistent behavior between your TTY logins and your ssh logins](http://serverfault.com/q/626346/152073).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PAM does not just do authentication, but authorisation and session services. You probably want to keep it on as it adds quite a bit of flexibility.

PAM will be called for a successful pubkey authentication, because session and account services are still checked.

PAM can do things SSH cannot. This list is not exhaustive:

- Deny a user access if SELinux is not in enforcing mode (if thats your thing).
- Set resource limits like max processes and max logins allowed.
- Flexibly deny a user based off of their user and remote source IP (possible in SSH too, but is pretty terse in PAM)
- Setup a series of environment variables you may want to pass.
- Create a home directory for a user if it did not exist.
- Deny users based off of the time/date of their access attempt.
- Deny inactive users.
- Deny users using an invalid shell.
- Setup key logging facilities of input.